# Bookshelves: the intruder

Tags: lateral-thinking, visual, odd-one-out

Somebody has messed up my bookshelf by shoving a book into completely the wrong place.

**Which is the intruder?**

[image]

Comment: Would you like to comment on whether you mean a book _that shouldn't be on this shelf at all_ or one that _should be in a different position_? (I _think_ you mean the former and it might well be that there's no particular ordering to the correctly-placed book. But it seems worth checking. Of course you might prefer not to answer...)

Comment: Good question...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The wrong book is

> *Vicious Circles and Infinity* (the second one)

because

> the first letter of each other title spells out "my bookshelf".

Comment: Very good. Well done!

Answer (score 14):

**Obviously wrong answer**

... but it amuses me and it might amuse OP too. Perhaps the book that's in the wrong place is

> Oliver Twist

because

> it belongs [over here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83616/bookshelves-2-what-am-i-reading), between *Bleak House* and *The Murder of Roger Ackroyd*.

Comment: Ha, yes. 11 next to 10. Very good!

Comment: What a twist! :D

Comment: @Brandon_J Ha! Nice one!

Answer (score 7):

> Probably not the correct answer, because it's too straightforward, but each of the books is a proper book, but *Birds Songs & Calls* is multimedia - it comes with 2 CDs